# Pandas date calculation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm just starting to learn python, and was trying to make it do something useful for my work.

My objective is to read a table from an excel file with data of the following format, and do some calculations on it:
This is the service record of days worked by an employee:

```
Day from    Day to
01/09/12    31/08/13
04/07/15    10/11/15
11/11/17
```

In the last row, Day to is not given, and would be taken as the current date.

I wrote the following:

```
import pandas
db=pandas.read_excel('earnedleaves.xls')
from datetime import datetime
def Calc_Days_Worked(dtentry, dtexit):
    if type(dtexit) is pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType:
        dtexit = pandas.Timestamp.now.to_pydatetime()        
        return (dtexit-dtentry.to_pydatetime()).days

    return (dtexit.to_pydatetime()-dtentry.to_pydatetime()).days

for (dtfrom, dtto) in zip(db['Day from'], db['Day to']):    
  print (Calc_Days_Worked(dtfrom, dtto))
```

It's working very well except for the last row, where a NaT type is encountered. I'm unable to subtract days with this value as it is returning an error. Obviously I'm not using the right data type. I've been experimenting with various types in datetime and pandas Timestamp, but can't workout the right way to convert the current date to a type compatible with pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-b44dc7b7c4c2> in <module>()
      2     print (dtfrom, dtto)
      3 #     print (type(dtfrom))
----> 4     print (Calc_Days_Worked(dtfrom, dtto))

<ipython-input-51-0e4a2d290dce> in Calc_Days_Worked(dtentry, dtexit)
      2 def Calc_Days_Worked(dtentry, dtexit):
      3     if type(dtexit) is pandas._libs.tslib.NaTType:
----> 4         dtexit = pandas.Timestamp.now.to_pydatetime()
      5         return (dtexit-dtentry.to_pydatetime()).days
      6 

AttributeError: 'cython_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need pandas functions because working with `NaN` and `NaT` values also - first convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)s and then get [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
db['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(db['Day to']) - pd.to_datetime(db['Day from'])).dt.days
print (db)
   Day from    Day to   diff
0  01/09/12  31/08/13  600.0
1  04/07/15  10/11/15  187.0
2  11/11/17       NaN    NaN
```

Also if need process datetimes later:

```
db['Day to'] = pd.to_datetime(db['Day to'])
db['Day from'] = pd.to_datetime(db['Day from'])
db['diff'] = (db['Day to'] - db['Day from']).dt.days
print (db)
    Day from     Day to   diff
0 2012-01-09 2013-08-31  600.0
1 2015-04-07 2015-10-11  187.0
2 2017-11-11        NaT    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. It's amazing to know pandas is so intuitive!

Comment: @Droidzone - Yes, it is reason why I like it :)